# Как вывести из Ajax запроса только city_name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

мне нужны через ajax запрос вывести города, сейчас выводит помимо городов и другие занчения [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]. Как мне вывести значение city_name в ul class="cities-dropdown__menu" в виде li ?

Comment: кто такой city_name и откуда он берётся?вопрос задан второй раз и всё тоже самое осталось - с прошлого раза - явная недосказанность

Comment: CSS тут точно лишний :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 success: function (data) {
    data.forEach(city => {
        $('.cities-dropdown__menu').append(`<li class="number-cities__item">${city.city_name}</li>`);
    })
 }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]